# While performing multiobjective optimization, cplex status = -1. why?

Tags: multithreading, function, error-handling, cplex

I have entered three objectives in my problem. The problem shown is as follows:

Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: 19118; 15 Unknown OPL Problem Marker CPLEX status = -1

Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
IBM ILOG CPLEX Exception: MultipleObjException: IloCplex cannot handle multiple objectives. Unknown OPL Problem Marker 19118;15
My objective functions are;

minimize 0.5*(sum(i in tavail)0.5*((pt[i]-pl[i])));

maximize 0.25*(sum (i in tavail)(sum (j in number)(c[i]*pevdis[i][j])));

minimize 0.25* (sum (i in tavail)(sum (j in number)(c[i]*pevch[i][j])));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a model you can have 0 or 1 (Maximize or Minimize)

But you can write

```
minimize 0.5*(sum(i in tavail)0.5*((pt[i]-pl[i])))

- 0.25*(sum (i in tavail)(sum (j in number)(c[i]*pevdis[i][j])))

+0.25* (sum (i in tavail)(sum (j in number)(c[i]*pevch[i][j])));
```

or if you want to rely on lexicographic multiobjective

```
minimize staticLex(0.5*(sum(i in tavail)0.5*((pt[i]-pl[i]))),

-0.25*(sum (i in tavail)(sum (j in number)(c[i]*pevdis[i][j])),

+0.25* (sum (i in tavail)(sum (j in number)(c[i]*pevch[i][j]))));
```

PS:

You ask many questions so let me share some [entry points](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/low-barrier-entry-optimization-through-cplex-alex-fleischer/) for learning more about cplex

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any training courses available for C-PLEX?

Comment: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/discussion/training-in-opl

Comment: Sir, I am no longer getting answers to questions on C-PLEX software from stack over flow. I have also posted my query in the IBM Decisions Optimization Forum. Will I get the answers?